# Installing GCC 4.8.2 on Red Hat Enterprise linux 6.5

Tags: linux, gcc, gmp, mpfr, mpc

I am new to Red Hat Enterprise linux.
I am facing issues while compiling gcc 4.8.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5
I down;oaded the source code from GNU webite.
I followed steps from this link
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC
Commands fired are:

```
tar xzf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.6.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.2/configure 

checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... gnatbind
checking for gnatmake... gnatmake
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... yes
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... no
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.
```

I investigated on Google then i find following question related to this
http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-02/msg00142.html
but it again redirected me to above link which i found and followed earlier.

I need guidance about how to proceed with this issue.
Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As mentioned,you have to have the mentioned libraries as shown in the error log---`gmp`,`mpfr` and `mpc`!

Comment: i think using `yum info` you can know if you have that utilities installed or not.

Comment: Consider just installing the Redhat Developer Toolset, which is an add-on that packages more recent versions of some important development software, including GCC.  The commercial RedHat version is here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/  The free identical CentOS version (works on RHEL) is here: http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/

Comment: Are you building GCC for fun/learning or because you need a newer version?

Comment: I see both 4.6.2 and 4.8.2 in your post, did you consistently type the same version?

Comment: @Marc: Yes that was typo it is 4.8.2

Answer (score 9):

The official way to have gcc 4.8.2 on RHEL 6 is via installing Red Hat Developer Toolset (yum install devtoolset-2), and in order to have it you need to have one of the below subscriptions:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Support, Professional
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Support, Enterprise
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation, Professional
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation, Enterprise
- 30 day Self-Supported Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation Evaluation
- 60 day Supported Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation Evaluation
- 90 day Supported Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation Evaluation
- 1-year Unsupported Partner Evaluation Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- 1-year Unsupported Red Hat Advanced Partner Subscription

You can check whether you have any of these subscriptions by running:

`subscription-manager list --available`

and

`subscription-manager list --consumed`.

If you don't have any of these subscriptions, you won't succeed in "yum install devtoolset-2". However, luckily cern provide a "back door" for their SLC6 which can also be used in RHEL 6. Run below three lines via root, and you should be able to have it:

`wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`

`wget -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/5x/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern`

`yum install devtoolset-2`

Once it's done completely, you should have the new development package in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/.

Comment: Please use http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/obsolete/5x/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern for the Key URL

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the mpc/mpfr/gmp packages aren't being downloaded. Just look in your gcc source directory, it should have created symlinks to those packages:

```
gcc/4.9.1/install$ ls -ad gmp mpc mpfr
gmp  mpc  mpfr
```

If those don't show up then simply download them from the gcc site: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/

Then untar and symlink/rename them so you have the directories like above. Then when you ./configure and make, gcc's makefile will automatically build them for you.